# Method not found: 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.Convert

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-standard

use case:

I'm trying to consume .net Core 2.0 libraries via a .net Standard 2.0 nuGet package to be able to consume them inside a .net Framework 4.6.1 project

I have come across the following exception whilst trying to convert a .net Core 2.0 library to .net Standard 2:

```
Method not found: 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.Convert(Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpBinderFlags, System.Type, System.Type)'.
```

I have tried looking through my code to find a reference to this from my stack trace however it points to a very simple method.

I'm trying to find the reference to this method in a working codebase which is completely .net core based.

My question is: How do I search in Visual Studio to find where this method is called and how to potentially fix the issue?

Comment: Have you run the .Net portability analyzer to check what is portable and what require code changes?

Comment: Add a reference to `Microsoft.CSharp` in your project

Comment: @user1672994 . Thank for commenting, I've just tried the portability check and it says 100% compatible with .net Standard

Comment: @Alberto. I've added it to the parent project and the error still persists. Does it need installing in the NuGet I'm trying to use?

Comment: @MrGiggles you should add it to the .net standard2 library using nuget